# How to get parent id

Tags: odoo

I want to recuper contrat_parent_id in model 'facturation.lot' for filtring.

Models :

```python
class Contrat(models.Model):
    _name = 'facturation.contrat'

    code = fields.Char(string='Numéro Contrat', required=True)
    contrat_parent_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat', string='Numéro Contrat Client')


class Lot(models.Model):
    _name = 'facturation.lot'
    _description = 'Lots'

    contrat_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat', ondelete='cascade')
    articlecontrat_ids = fields.Many2many('facturation.articleouvrage',string='Article Lot')

class ArticleOuvrage(models.Model):
    _name = 'facturation.articleouvrage'
    _description = 'Ligne Articles'

    article_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.article',string='Article')
    ouvrage_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.ouvrage',string="Ouvrage")
```

View :

```xml
<record id="lot_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">facturation.lot.form</field>
   <field name="model">facturation.lot</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <form>
           <sheet>
               <field name="lib_lot" string="Lot"/>
               <field name="contrat_id" options="{'no_create':True}"></field>
               <notebook>
                   <page string="Composants" >
                       <field name="articlecontrat_ids" domain="[('ouvrage_id.contrat_id.id','=',1)]" options="{'no_create':True}" >
                           <tree>
```

I want to recuper contrat_parent_id in model 'facturation.lot' for filtring.
thanks

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: I want to recuper 'contrat_parent_id' of the model 'facturation.contrat' in model 'facturation.lot' for filtring domain="[('ouvrage_id.contrat_id.id','=',????????)]"